# C++ Merge sort slower with threads

Tags: c++, algorithm, performance, sorting

I've implemented a merge sort algorithm in C++.
Inside the algorithms it checks if the size of the array is larger than `min_size_to_thread` and if it is: calls the function recursively with threads instead.

But when I increase `min_size_to_thread`: which decreases the number of threads being used, the function becomes faster. Even when going from 1 to 2 threads.

My hypothesis was that the function speed would increase with more threads up to a point and then start decreasing again. This just doesn't make any sense to me, so I'm starting to believe my implementation is wrong somehow.

```
template <typename T>
void merge_sort(T S[], int S_size, int min_size_to_thread)
{
    if (S_size < 2) return;

    // Left Sequence
    int L_size = S_size / 2;
    T* L = new T[L_size];
    for (int i = 0; i < L_size; i++)
    {
        L[i] = S[i];
    }

    // Right Sequence
    int R_size = (S_size + 1) / 2;
    T* R = new T[R_size];
    for (int i = 0; i < R_size; i++)
    {
        R[i] = S[i + L_size];
    }

    if (S_size > min_size_to_thread)
    {
        std::thread thread_left(merge_sort<T>, L, L_size, min_size_to_thread);
        std::thread thread_right(merge_sort<T>, R, R_size, min_size_to_thread);
        thread_right.join();
        thread_left.join();
    }
    else
    {
        merge_sort<T>(L, L_size, min_size_to_thread);
        merge_sort<T>(R, R_size, min_size_to_thread);
    }

    int S_iterator = 0;
    int L_iterator = 0;
    int R_iterator = 0;

    while ((L_iterator < L_size) && (R_iterator < R_size))
    {
        if (L[L_iterator] < R[R_iterator])
        {
            S[S_iterator] = L[L_iterator];
            ++L_iterator;
        }
        else
        {
            S[S_iterator] = R[R_iterator];
            ++R_iterator;
        }
        ++S_iterator;
    }

    while (L_iterator < L_size)
    {
        S[S_iterator] = L[L_iterator];
        ++L_iterator;
        ++S_iterator;
    }

    while (R_iterator < R_size)
    {
        S[S_iterator] = R[R_iterator];
        ++R_iterator;
        ++S_iterator;
    }

    delete[] L;
    delete[] R;
}

int main()
{
    const int S_size = 500000;
    unsigned char S[S_size];
    for (int i = 0; i < S_size; ++i)
    {
        S[i] = i % 255;
    }

    int min_size_to_thread;

    min_size_to_thread = 250;
    auto t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    merge_sort(S, S_size, min_size_to_thread);
    auto t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::cout << "size > " << min_size_to_thread << ": " << (t2 - t1) / std::chrono::milliseconds(1) << std::endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < S_size; ++i)
    {
        S[i] = i % 255;
    }

    min_size_to_thread = 500;
    t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    merge_sort(S, S_size, min_size_to_thread);
    t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::cout << "size > " << min_size_to_thread << ": " << (t2 - t1) / std::chrono::milliseconds(1) << std::endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < S_size; ++i)
    {
        S[i] = i % 255;
    }

    min_size_to_thread = 1000;
    t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    merge_sort(S, S_size, min_size_to_thread);
    t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::cout << "size > " << min_size_to_thread << ": " << (t2 - t1) / std::chrono::milliseconds(1) << std::endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < S_size; ++i)
    {
        S[i] = i % 255;
    }

    min_size_to_thread = 10000;
    t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    merge_sort(S, S_size, min_size_to_thread);
    t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::cout << "size > " << min_size_to_thread << ": " << (t2 - t1) / std::chrono::milliseconds(1) << std::endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < S_size; ++i)
    {
        S[i] = i % 255;
    }

    min_size_to_thread = 250000;
    t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    merge_sort(S, S_size, min_size_to_thread);
    t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::cout << "size > " << min_size_to_thread << ": " << (t2 - t1) / std::chrono::milliseconds(1) << std::endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < S_size; ++i)
    {
        S[i] = i % 255;
    }

    min_size_to_thread = 500000;
    t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    merge_sort(S, S_size, min_size_to_thread);
    t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::cout << "size > " << min_size_to_thread << ": " << (t2 - t1) / std::chrono::milliseconds(1) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

[image]

Comment: You should not by copying the sub arrays.  That is going to kill your performance.  Just keep one array and then pass the indexes you are working with, although that will cause false sharing issues.

Comment: @NathanOliver is that the reason it's slower with threads?

Comment: It could very well be.

Comment: There's no point in using `thread_right` at all, since you create it and immediately wait on it (after waiting on left), so the original thread won't do anything until it finishes.  After creating the left thread, do the right thread stuff in the current thread then wait for the left to complete.

Comment: Your implementation creates and then joins two threads, while you have one already hot & scheduled thread park itself for no reason. You should at least sort the left in a new thread while sorting the right in the current thread (and then join) or vice-versa.

Comment: better yet: use [std::async](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async) to sort the left, and sort the right on the current thread. `std::async` may use a thread pool, which can make things run a little faster than when creating a new thread each time.

Comment: "threads = 500000" ? On my Ubuntu desktop, each thread is limited to a default automatic-memory of 8 M bytes (i.e. Linux stack).  What an interesting hint about the kind of equipment you are working with!

Comment: @2785528 the `threads` variable doesn't hold the number of threads. It actually holds the size of the sub-array that will trigger a new thread creation. (Yes, the name is confusing)

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I've tried to only thread on left and have right run in the current thread like you told me, but the same pattern still occurs.

I agree, the name is confusing. Should be `min_size_to_thread` or something. I will change it.

Comment: Copying data will be slow: try to work in place. You're also creating and joining threads within your function; this has a large overhead. Instead, build a thread pool.

Comment: You should specify the processor, the compiler, and compiler options you used to compile and run the code. Use the x86 tag if appropriate.

Comment: I ran a similar test, except the number of threads was fixed in this [question about multi-threaded merge sort](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/148025/multithreaded-bottom-up-merge-sort). This example uses Windows native threading. The test I ran was for 16 million 32 bit integers. For 500,000 32 bit integers, 8 threads would take about  8.5 ms and 4 threads about 11 ms.

Comment: And having right run in a separate thread doubles the speed of the function. So I don't know why you're recommending to have it in the current thread, bad advice.

Comment: See interesting discussion on multithreading benefits in general in the [ACCU Overload 49 - 5 Big Fat Reasons Why Mutexes Suck Big Time](https://accu.org/var/uploads/journals/Overload149.pdf)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have compiled and run your exact program with no modifications other than adding includes and the results are more or less as you expected:

```
size > 250: 169
size > 500: 85
size > 1000: 50
size > 10000: 29
size > 250000: 42
size > 500000: 89
```

Based on your screen shot, I gather you are running your code from within Visual Studio. The default run button will attach a debugger to your executable and reduce the run time performance.  Instead, press Ctrl+F5 to run without a debugger or from the menu Debug -> Start Without Debugging.

Comment: Was this a release build or a debug build?

Comment: I built using cl.exe all default settings.

Comment: Weird. I tried to start without debugging, but I still get the same result (only everything is a lot faster). Got `875, 810, 761, 768, 536, 449`.

Comment: Changed to release x64 and start without debugger. Now I get the same results as you. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I think it is an issue with caching. To be specific **false-sharing** slows down the algorithm, because data is written to pages shared among multiple threads. (The different processor cores try to keep up with the shared memory pages) If the `min_size_to_thread` is a multiple of the **page-size** of your processor and your array is **aligned** on page-boundaries, the performance increases. In this case, pages will not be shared between the threads.

I always limit the creation of threads by a constant amount, it does not make sense to run 100 threads on a quad-core machine just to sort an array. **Running multiple threads on a single core costs due to heavy context switching.** In my experience the maximum thread-count is always the core-count times 2. **A single core can handle around 2 threads without a performance cost**. For a quad-core CPU, the program should run a maximum of 8 threads at once.
This means an algorithm could create 8 subthreads, the parent thread just `join`s the threads, **or** create 7 subthreads, run a part of the algorithm in the parent thread and finally `join` the other 7 threads.

Always profile, it could have a completely different reason.

Comment: I'm new so I will have to read about false-sharing and profiling. 
But to the second part of your answer: looking only at the last two tests where `min_size_to_thread = 250000` and `500000`: the first runs on two threads and the second on a single thread. Still the single thread is faster.